# How can I edit CSS on an HTML tab?

Tags: html, css, divshot

How can I edit the CSS directly on a tab which is displaying an HTML file? By clicking the "edit source" button, I can see the HTML, but not the CSS. Is there a way to see the CSS is a split panel view?

Comment: Are you saying in the browser ? There must be a "styles"/""computed styles" column or something similar to that in the browser. There you can edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question. We're working on CSS/JS editing in the split panel view within Divshot and it should be available very soon. I'll update this post when it's released.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the css file in your web browser then you can follow the below stapes-

In **google chrome** or **mozilla firefox** right click on the browser select inspect element -> inspector tab -> Rules -> edit the css value then you can see the changes css value is applied in your webpage.

Note:- It is applicable for tab, laptop, computer etc.